# "not as adjective as" or "a/an comparative adjective noun than"

Tags: comparison

> **This is the most interesting book I have ever read.**

If I change this sentence,

> I have never read a book as interesting as this.
>
> I have never read a more interesting book than this.

Which rule is better,"not as adjective as" or "a/an comparative adjective noun than" to rephrase the superlative?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking which of these sentences is *best*?  Because all of them are equally *good*, at least to communicate your opinion.  Example:

> She is the most beautiful woman I know.
>
> I have never known a more beautiful woman.
>
> I have never known a woman more beautiful than her.

All three tell the reader *exactly* what you think about her.  However, if you are writing for *effect*, or for contextual reasons you want to emphasize different parts of the sentence, each of these can *feel* different to the reader.  Also, with creative writing you might want a character to talk in a certain way, or develop a personal *rhythm* to your writing, where you naturally choose one of these over the others.

Another example:

> Now is the most uncertain time I have ever known.
>
> I have never known a more uncertain time than now.
>
> I have never known a time more uncertain than now.

Personally, if I am writing an article on the subject, I would pick the third.  I like the rhythm of the sentence, and the way it subtly emphasizes *now* by not revealing the time frame until the end of the sentence.  But there is no *grammatical* reason to pick it over the other two.